# Build on Jenkins fails: error: package com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client does not exist

Tags: java, jax-ws

I've added this line to my JAX-WS client

```
bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, this.timeoutRequest);
```

It builds just fine in IntelliJ, but the build can't complete on Jenkins. I'm getting `error: package com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client does not exist`

As I understand, I shouldn't use internal classes, so is there a different way of setting request timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project appears to use org.apache.cxf JAX WS implementation.

Used `org.apache.cxf.transports.http.configuration.HTTPClientPolicy` to set timeout.

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(this.timeout);
httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(this.timeout);
http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
```

There's more info in [Apache CXF docs](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport(includingSSLsupport)-HowtoconfiguretheHTTPConduitfortheSOAPClient?).